# Possible bug with Loopback4 inside findOne with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, express, loopback

### Description / Steps to reproduce / Feature proposal

I have only 2 models test and atest
test has (id,name,age)
atest has (testId) which refers to the id from test model

I have only 1 controller for (atest) with 2 ENDPOINTS
get '/eltest' > which findOne by the testId

```
return await this.atestRepository.findOne({where : {testId : "5ca358720916cec7fd29e875"}});
```

get '/anothertest' > which findOne by the id

```
return await this.atestRepository.findOne({where : {id : "5ca3589e0916cec7fd29e87a"}});
```

### Current Behavior

the first one works well - but the second one not find the exist record

### Expected Behavior

both should work and find the exist record inside the database

### Searches and solutions I tried with

changing @model() to @model({ settings: { strictObjectIDCoercion: true, }, }) inside atest model ;
works like a switch - it damage the working ENDPOINT and fix the damaged ENDPOINT

please use [this repo](https://github.com/frodoe7/LB4MongoFindOneIssue) to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 2 different repository for this case. See here

```
return await this.atestRepository.findOne({where : {id : "5ca3589e0916cec7fd29e87a"}});
```

atest model id column should correspond to id field in atest model. It can never be test model id. I think what you intend to do is

```
export class AtestController {
  constructor(
    @repository(AtestRepository)
    public atestRepository : AtestRepository,

    @repository(TestRepository)
    public testRepository : TestRepository,
  ) {}

  @get('/eltest', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Array of Atest model instances',
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: {type: 'array', items: {'x-ts-type': Atest}},
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
  async find() {
    return await this.atestRepository.findOne({where : {testId : "5ca358720916cec7fd29e875"}});
  }

  @get('/anothertest', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Array of Atest model instances',
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: {type: 'array', items: {'x-ts-type': Atest}},
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
  async findA() {
    return await this.testRepository.findOne({where : {id : "5ca3589e0916cec7fd29e87a"}});
  }
}
```

Note I am using testRepository here. That should work. Hope it helps.

Also please replace

```
@model({ settings: { strictObjectIDCoercion: true, }, })
```

with

```
@model()
```

Comment: atest model has an id column , I need to run this code in success ```return await this.atestRepository.findOne({where : {testId : "5ca358720916cec7fd29e875"}});
``` - you did not talk about it

Comment: I think that was working for you already. If you want I can put a fix in your repo itself to help you with solution. Will that be fine for you ? let me know.

Comment: @AhmedMohsen I have updated my answer with more context. Hope that works for you.

Comment: yes I noted that you used  ```return await this.testRepository.findOne({where : {id : "5ca3589e0916cec7fd29e87a"}});``` = but that's not what I need , I need to use this ```return await this.atestRepository.findOne({where : {id : "5ca3589e0916cec7fd29e87a"}});```
in my logic = I need to call it with atest repo

Comment: @AhmedMohsen, do you think your issue is related to the one mentioned here - https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1875 ? It is an open issue in that case.

Comment: Yes = I think it's related

Comment: Awesome. Then I think you should link your issue to that on lb4. For now, I think to solve your issue, you may need to avoid dataType as "ObjectID". If you keep it as simple string, that may work.